# Hide property in a subclass of a @ParameterObject with springdoc

Tags: openapi, springdoc

We are migrating from spring-fox to springdoc.

Sometimes we need to hide properties from common base classes that are used in @ParameterObjects.

With spring-fox (swagger2) this was working fine:

```java
    public class BaseParameters {
        private String baseProperty; 
    }
    
    class CustomizedParameters extends BaseParameters {
        @Override
        @ApiParam(hidden = true)
        public String getBaseProperty() {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The baseProperty doesn't show up in the api-docs

However with Springdoc this doesn't work:

```java
@ParameterObject
public class BaseParameters {
    private String baseProperty; 
}

@ParameterObject    
class CustomizedParameters extends BaseParameters {
    @Override
    @Hidden
    public String getBaseProperty() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also tried to hide the baseProperty with `@Parameter(hidden=true)` and `@JsonIgnore` but the property stays in the specs

What am I missing? Is this not supported in springdoc? Any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a work-around for this problem. But the annotations must be placed in attributes of classe.

The problem is in the `MethodParameterPojoExtractor` that not consider the annotation (Hidden, JsonIgnore ...) of child class attribute.

The code below using Reflections force the filling with Hidden annotation in method parameters generated.

OBS: In Case that the hierarchy of child class bigger 1, probably is throw Error. Because I make this in a hurry.

```java
@Bean
GenericParameterService parameterBuilder(PropertyResolverUtils propertyResolverUtils, Optional<WebConversionServiceProvider> optionalWebConversionServiceProvider) {
    return new GenericParameterService(propertyResolverUtils, delegatingMethodParameterCustomizer(),
                optionalWebConversionServiceProvider);
}

private Optional<DelegatingMethodParameterCustomizer> delegatingMethodParameterCustomizer() { // NOSONAR
    return Optional.of((originalMethodParam, methodParam) -> {
        if (originalMethodParam.hasParameterAnnotations()
            && originalMethodParam.hasParameterAnnotation(ParameterObject.class)
        ) {
            try {
                if (isParameterIgnore(originalMethodParam, methodParam)) {
                    Field field = FieldUtils.getDeclaredField(DelegatingMethodParameter.class, "additionalParameterAnnotations", true);
                    try {
                        field.set(methodParam, new Annotation[] {new Hidden() { // NOSONAR
                            @Override
                            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                                return Hidden.class;
                            }}
                        });
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException|IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
    
private boolean isParameterIgnore(MethodParameter originalMethodParam, MethodParameter methodParam) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    String parameterName = Objects.requireNonNullElse(methodParam.getParameterName(), "");
    String fieldName = parameterName.indexOf('.') == -1 ? parameterName : parameterName.substring(0, parameterName.indexOf('.'));
    Field declaredField; 
    try {
        declaredField = originalMethodParam.getParameterType().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        declaredField = originalMethodParam.getParameterType().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    }
    return Stream.of(declaredField.getAnnotations())
        .filter(annot -> List.of(Hidden.class, JsonIgnore.class).contains(annot.annotationType())).count() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to apply this work-around? did you patch the MethodParameterPojoExtractor?

Comment: Just create a `GenericParameterService` Bean in you SwaggerConfig class, passing the method `delegatingMethodParameterCustomizer` into parameters. See the answer again, i just inserted the bean declaration.